# AngularJS: $http success callback

Tags: ajax, angularjs

I'm a little confused how to implement the callback from a successful AJAX call to my RESTful server. This is how I fetch the data:

Service:

```
app.factory('Data', function($http) {
    var factory = {};

    factory.get = function(id, success, error) {
        $http.post("/api/"+id).success(success);

    return factory
    };
```

I prefer having self defined functions (e.g. factory.get()) to use in my controller.

Controller:

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, Data) {

    var onSuccess = function(data, status) {
       // I want to append something to the DOM here
       }
    };

    $scope.get = function(id) {
       Data.get(id, onSuccess)
    };
});
```

Here I'm defining a get function I can use in my HTML and I have to pass in an id. However, I have no idea how to access the element so I can append the information from the JSON response to the DOM in the onSuccess function.

Do I have to create a directive to accomplish this? Is this a right way to make AJAX calls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the server response to be accessible inside the DOM, it needs to be in the scope of your controller. 
You can do this by assigning the returned data to a $scope variable inside the success callback:

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, Data) {
    $scope.get = function(id) {
        Data.get(id).success(function(data, status) {
            $scope.status = status;
            $scope.data = data;
        });
    };
});
```

Now you can simply refer to `$scope.data` as `data` inside the HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data">
    {{item}}
</div>
```

Comment: So if I want to append another element I should already create it but just not show it and when I want to show it change the ng-show to true? And my AJAX call are done ok? cause they look kinda messy

Comment: If you want to add elements to DOM conditionally then you can use `ng-if` directive available in  v1.1.5.

Comment: I get the sense that as an Angular best practice you should keep your Logic in the Controller, and DOM manipulation in Directives leaning on `ng-if` only when you need to.